# Consul : pass values to nomad jobs

Tags: docker, consul, nomad

I have this consul kv

```
 curl -XPUT http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/consul-server1/testData -d HELLO
```

how can i call/pass it in nomad job as env variable?

```
 env { "data"= ? }
```

Comment: Check this out https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/job-specification/template.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a value to nomad from Consul kv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56801967/passing-a-value-to-nomad-from-consul-kv)