# Passing a value to nomad from Consul kv

Tags: consul, nomad

fetch the information from Consul and then submit this job to Nomad, injecting the Consul k/v value as an environment variable.

like for example i have a value in consul k/v which is

```
testData = "HELLO"
```

on the other hand, in my job.

i want the value from consul k/v to be injected to env stanza as a value.

```
env
CONSUL_test = <value of consul k/v testData>
```

is this possible?

so that when i inspect the docker env, i must see

```
CONSUL_test = HELLO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nomad uses consul-templating, so you can reference consul k/v values in your nomad spec by doing `{{ key "myKey" }}`. https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/job-specification/template.html